# Is it possible to use process explorer to kill a recursive loop generated in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, process-explorer

Sometimes I incorrectly code something and I create a thread that enters a never ending loop. this means I have to shut down the entire visual studio. Is it possible to use process explorer to inspect the visual studio process and shut down the thread that is killing the cpu?

Pete

Answer (score 1):

Erm... yes? Normally you can just press "stop" (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>) when debugging, but otherwise just locate your app (in task manager or any other tool; typically just a case of sorting by CPU usage) and end the process. VS will treat that as your process exiting, but VS *itself* should be fairly unharmed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use Process Explorer to kill a single thread. You kill the entire process. You could use [SysInternals procexp.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to analyze processes and threads and kill only a single thread within a given process. Very nifty tool. But in general avoid coding never ending loops :-)

Comment: Yes that would be the best thing :-) however how do I access the threads in the process? (i am using procexp.exe)

Comment: Double click on a process and look at the Threads tab. Once you've identified the victim, there's a Kill button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

But doesn't the Visual Studio Debugger have an 'stop'-button or something alike?

Comment: How do I do this then I can only see the devenv.exe in the process explorer. And the gui for visual studio is locked (trying to service the request I guess).

Comment: You can only kill the entire process, not a single thread.

Just locate your process in task manager (ctrl+alt+del) and kill your task. (Usually the one with high cpu usage)